# Polymer this and Cytoscape this

Tags: javascript, polymer, cytoscape.js

So I have a problem and it's most likely because I still don't get JavaScript... Cytoscape has their own 'this' and Polymer has their 'this'

```html
    <div id="labelFld">{{node.label}}</div>
    <div id="measureFld">{{node.measure}}</div>
    <div id="timesignatureFld">{{node.time_signature}}</div>
    <div id="voiceFld">{{node.voice}}</div>
    <div id="beatFld">{{node.beat}}</div>
    <div id="meventFld">{{node.event}}</div>
```

```js
var cy;
cytoscape({
    ready : function () {
              Polymer: ({
                ...
                        properties : {
                                node : {
                                type : Object,
                                notify : true,
                                readOnly : true
                        }
                },
                ...
```

```js
// Fires when the local DOM has been fully prepared
ready : function () {
    var self_node = this.node; // <- 'this' via Polymer
    try {
        cy = cytoscape({
                container : this.$.rhythmgraph,
                ready : function (e) {}
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    // Assign handler to Cytoscape click event for node elements
    cy.on('click', 'node', {
        "nodedata" : self_node // <- Seems to pass by value, not reference
    }, function (e) {
        self_node = this.data(); // <- 'this' via Cytoscape
        console.log(self_node);
        // e.data.nodedata = this.data();
    });
},
```

But in order to update my `<div>{{node.label}}</div>` I have to be able to do `this.node.label = "N42" // Polymer` but I can't do it in the `cy.on('click','node', ... )` because I need `this.data() // Cytoscape` inside there.

Scope is really killing me on this.

*EDIT*

In the end, I created an Observer to watch and update:

```js
    self_node = this.selectedNode;
    var poly = this;

    Object.observe(self_node, function(changes) {
      changes.forEach(function(change) {
        if(change.type == "update") {
        poly.selectedNode = {
          "id":     change.object.id,
...                                  }
        };
        poly.notifyPath('selectedNode.id', change.object.id);

      }
     });}.bind(poly));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this a common gotcha among JS dev beginners. You'll have to bind the function to its proper `this` reference.

```
cy.on('click', 'node', {
    "nodedata" : rhynode
}, function (e) {
    e.data.nodedata = this.data();
    console.log(e.data.nodedata);
}.bind(this)); // here
```

With ES2015, arrow functions would bind automatically to the proper `this`:

```
cy.on('click', 'node', {
    "nodedata" : rhynode
}, (e) => {
    e.data.nodedata = this.data();
    console.log(e.data.nodedata);
});
```

Comment: for `cy.on('click'...{ ... }.bind(this));` it replaces cytoscape's `this` with polymer's `this` - I need to keep both, but have polymer's `this` be a reference to `this.node` and not a copied value via `var rhynode = this.node`.

By adding the `.bind(this)` it returns `Uncaught TypeError: this.data is not a function`

Comment: @Manchuwook Try this `var self_node = this.node`. Then use that variable.

Comment: Okay, I've done `var self_node = this.node` at the Polymer ready() scope and in the `cy.on('click','node', (e) => { self_node = this.data() })` used the variable and it still seems to set the local value and not update the referenced property.

Comment: You'll probably have to use the `self` method as Cytoscape.js sets `this` for callbacks in listeners: http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/events/eles.on (That' probably something that should be changed for 3.0)

Comment: So far @NeilJohnRamal had it correct, but I misunderstood at what point I do the assignment - which is to not use it in the parameter list for cy.on() and instead use it in the event function body.  I seem to have an issue with the Polymer _object_Changed event now when it comes to binding.

Comment: It gets worse - I can't call either `notifyPath` or `_notifyPath` (from Polymer) as it still thinks `this` is Cytoscape.

Comment: @Manchuwook Are you using the arrow function syntax? Don't. Get back to using the long way instead.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal I have not used any arrow functions in my code.  I eventually got it working, but I have to use an Observer to watch self_node and manually call the notifyPath method for Polymer.